# Equivalent of mllib.DecisionTreeModel.toDebugString() in ml.DecisionTreeClassificationModel

Tags: java, apache-spark, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

As the question says, is there any equivalent of Spark `org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeClassificationModel.toDebugString()` in `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel`

I have gone through the API doc of the latter and found this method `rootNode()` which gives back a `org.apache.spark.ml.tree.Node` object which seems to be a recursive object, so should I use this class instead to build the tree structure myself?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel already have a toDebugString() method implemented because it has DecisionTreeModel as a trait.

Example:

```
class org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel
DecisionTreeClassificationModel of depth 1 with 3 nodes
  If (feature 378 <= 71.0)
   Predict: 1.0
  Else (feature 378 > 71.0)
   Predict: 0.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot, wonder why it does not have this method mentioned in java API docs...