# Equivalent of pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTreeModel.toDebugString() in pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel - IN PYTHON

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

This is essentially the same question as:

- [Equivalent of mllib.DecisionTreeModel.toDebugString() in ml.DecisionTreeClassificationModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678365/equivalent-of-mllib-decisiontreemodel-todebugstring-in-ml-decisiontreeclassifi)

**BUT for pyspark.**

I used to be able to do something like:

```
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo=categoricalFeatures, impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=16)
print model.toDebugString()
```

and I would get a nice visualization of the decision tree:

```
DecisionTreeModel classifier of depth 5 with 49 nodes
  If (feature 1 in {0.0})
   If (feature 0 in {0.0})
    If (feature 2 <= 52.0)
     If (feature 3 <= 26.0)
      Predict: 0.0
...
```

I am trying to port my code to pyspark.ml, but I don't see any way of printing the resulting tree

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", maxDepth=5, maxBins=16, impurity='gini')
model = dt.fit(transformedTrainingData)
```

When I do:

```
print model
```

I only get the first line:

```
DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=DecisionTreeClassifier_4cbda3dcd0bddd9d4a0b) of depth 5 with 43 nodes
```

Thoughts on how to get the nice tree output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  It is not elegant and it violates encapsulation and everything you ever learned about object oriented programming, but it works:

```
print model._call_java("toDebugString")

DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=DecisionTreeClassifier_4c3bb548827f07c590e6) of depth 5 with 49 nodes
  If (feature 1 in {0.0})
   If (feature 0 in {1.0,2.0})
    If (feature 2 <= 5.0)
     If (feature 3 <= 26.0)
      Predict: 1.0
     Else (feature 3 > 26.0)
      If (feature 0 in {2.0})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Now (in Spark 2.2) you can also simply call:

```
print(model.toDebugString)
```

You're gonna get something like:

```
DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=DecisionTreeClassifier_48b398caca43f9fd5bc1) of depth 15 with 5237 nodes
  If (feature 39 <= 0.09)
   If (feature 11 <= 369.79999999999995)
    If (feature 33 <= 217.75400000000002)
     If (feature 4 <= 3864.0)
      If (feature 33 <= -0.01)
       If (feature 12 <= 2950.0)
        If (feature 33 <= -64.83)
```